# Apache beam / Scala Combine perkey

Tags: java, scala, apache-beam

I'm looking for someone to provide a working example of using Apache beam Combine.perkey transform in Scala using the beam Java API.

I'm coming across issues with the scala/java type interoperability.

I can't get combine per key to work. I can never get it to be correct in syntax.

Example:

```
val sales: PCollection KV[(Int,Int), Long]

sales.apply(Combine.perKey[(Int,Int),Long,Long](new SumLongs()))

import org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.SerializableFunction

class SumLongs extends SerializableFunction[Iterable[Long], Long] {
  override def apply(input: Iterable[Long]): Long = {
  var sum = 0L
  for (item <- input) {
    sum += item
  }
  sum
  }
}
```

It gives error, "too many type arguments for perkey". When I take that out, it states "Unspecified type parameters: OutputT".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just needed to change scala Iterable with java.lang.Iterable